# Reading / Writing to several launched processes command lines

Tags: c#, .net, windows, f#

I was wondering if it is possible to read the input stream / write to the output stream of several launched processes.

I'm asking this as from my current (weak) understanding of how reading / writing to launched processes work, it surely looks as it attaches the input / output streams to my program's console input / output stream.

Is this, indeed, the case? If that's the case, then reading/writing different data to several launched command lines would prove complicated, if not impossible, not achieve.

Is my understanding correct? How to deal with several launched command lines?

---

Some code:

```ml
open System
open System.IO
open System.Diagnostics
open System.Threading

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let startInfo = ProcessStartInfo()
    startInfo.FileName <- "cmd.exe"
    startInfo.UseShellExecute <- false
    startInfo.RedirectStandardInput <- true
    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput <- true
    let proc = Process.Start(startInfo)
    proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("svn log")
    Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
    0
```

This code, as it is, will print

```
svn: E155007: 'C:\x\y\z\bin\Debug' is not a working copy
```

Comment: Are you launching the commands, or are they already existing?

Comment: I'm launching them through System.Diagnostics.Process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> " it surely looks as it attaches the input / output streams to my
>   program's console input / output stream."

Not true.  You can tell the process to redirect stdin via `myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput`.  The `Process` object exposes methods to get to the input/output streams (e.g. `Process.StandardInput`) to read/write them.

MSDN  has some decent example code:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: If you set RedirectStandardInput/Output to true and attempt to write to Process.StandardInput, you'll get the output on your console.

Comment: You should redirect the standard output as well.

Comment: I am redirecting it, too (as stated originally).

Comment: You should *also* `RedirectStandardError` is my guess.